# Error when trying to use more than 48 KB of (static) shared memory

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am trying to statically allocate a `__shared__` variable using a device architecture of `sm_86`. If the size of the variable is larger than 48 KB, `nvcc` complains about it and fails to compile with error

```
Entry function uses too much shared data
```

I am running Visual Studio 2019 with CUDA 11.2 and have set

```
Configuration properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Device -> Code Generation
```

to `compute_86,sm_86`

According to the table [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) should not devices of cc 8.6 allow for a maximum shared memory per block of 100 KB?

Here is a simple code sample that fails on me:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#define SIZE 12288 /* x 4 byte = 48 KB <---- Works */
/* #define SIZE 12289 */ /* <---- Fails */

__global__ void kernel(int* d) {
    __shared__ int s[SIZE];
    s[threadIdx.x] = 1;
    d[threadIdx.x] = s[threadIdx.x];

}

int main() {
    int* d_a;
    cudaMalloc(&d_a, SIZE * sizeof(int));
    kernel <<<1, 1024 >>> (d_a);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(d_a);
}
```

Comment: note from the linked duplicate that accessing more than 48KB requires not only the opt-in mechanism via the API call, but it also requires that you use dynamically allocated shared memory.  You are using statically allocated shared memory here, that is always limited to 48KB.

Comment: Understood. Thanks very much for your help. Appreciate it!

Comment: @RobertCrovella: IIANM, your comment about static shared memory doesn't appear in the dupe - for which reason I believe the question should be reopened and the comment made an answer.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation quote in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: IMHO the text there is a bit obscure. I would rather we edited that question and answer to focus more on dynamic shared memory; reopened this one; and answered it to focus on static shared memory.

Comment: I've already updated the other answer to cover fairly explicitly both the static and dynamic case.